# Given the corner points of two rectangular prisms, find the corner points of the overlapping rectangular prism

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, geometry, overlap

If I'm given the corner points of two rectangular prisms in 3d space, one of which is centred around (0,0,0), in general terms, what would be an elegant and efficient way of finding the corner points of the overlapping rectangular prism, or returning nothing if the two rectangular prisms do not overlap?

Comment: Are both prisms axis-aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that by 'the overlapping rectangular prism,' you mean the intersection of the two prisms.  Also, I assume they are axis-aligned.

Let the lower bound of prism A be denoted by `[xmina, ymina, zmina]` and the lower bound of prism B by `[xminb, yminb, zminb]`.  Similarly, denote the upper bounds as `[xmaxa, ymaxa, zmaxa]` and `[xmaxb, ymaxb, zmaxb]`.

The intersection is non-empty if and only if `max(xmina, xminb) < min(xmaxa, xmaxb) ^ max(ymina, yminb) < min(ymaxa, ymaxb) ^ max(zmina, zminb) < min(zmaxa, zmaxb)` where `^` means 'and'.

Then the lower and upper x bounds of the intersection are given by `max(xmina, xminb)` and `min(xmaxa, xmaxb)`, similarly for y and z.